# Unknown error in code to find the angle necessary for a rocket to land on the moon

Tags: matlab, loops, physics

I need to find the angle of a rocket given the conditions in the code that enables it to land on the moon. The moon is taken as stationary at the given coordinates. I assumed the only way to try would just be calculating the different velocity components and then inputting them for each angle from the minimum to the maximum, which is what I've tried to do.

Not sure why this isn't working - it just runs forever and doesn't output anything.

Thank you.

I have

```
v = 0.0066;

for angle = 0:.5:180

init_vel = [v*cosd(angle), v*sind(angle)];
init_pos = [3.7,0];
t = 10;
moon_pos = [0,222];
%simulate rocket
[tout, pos] = simulaterocketmovement(init_pos, init_vel, moon_pos, t);

    if(length(tout)<99999)
        break;
    end
 end

 disp(angle);

 plot(pos(:,1),pos(:,2));
```

where

```
function [ tout , pos ] = simulaterocketmovement ( init_pos , init_vel , moon_pos , t)

%Defining initial variables for later use
G = 9.63*10^-7;
Me = 83.3;

%Defining the two vectors we will use
x = init_pos(1);
y = init_pos(2);
vx = init_vel(1);
vy = init_vel(2);


%Need to create a seperate function that integrates to find the
%acceleration using Euler's second order method.
function a = acc(x,y)
    ax = -(G*Me*x)/((x^2 + y^2)^1.5) - (G*(x-moon_pos(1)))/(((moon_pos(1)-x)^2 + (moon_pos(2)-y)^2)^1.5);
    ay = -(G*Me*y)/((x^2 + y^2)^1.5) - (G*(y-moon_pos(2)))/(((moon_pos(1)-x)^2 + (moon_pos(2)-y)^2)^1.5);
    %After finding the vector components, we put them in an acceleration vector.
    a = [ax,ay];
end  


%Now we find the values which result in the rocket landing on the moon. The
%range of values lie between xmin and xmax, and ymin and ymax. The +/-
%represents that the rocket can land anywhere on the moon's surface.
xmax = moon_pos(1) + 1;
xmin = moon_pos(1) - 1;
ymax = moon_pos(2) + 1;
ymin = moon_pos(2) - 1;


%For each time taken, to find the x and y values we need to use a while
%loop which works until the rocket is in the range of values for it to
%land on the moon.
while((x(end) > xmax) || (x(end) < xmin) || (y(end) < ymin) || (y(end) > ymax) )

%We assign temporary new values of x and y.
x(end+1) = x(end) + t*vx;
y(end+1) = y(end) + t*vy;

%Then we find the values of acceleration for both the old and new x and y 
aold = acc(x(end-1), y(end-1));
anew = acc(x(end), y(end));

%Using this to find the new velocities
vxnew = vx + t*(aold(1)+anew(1))/2;
vynew = vy + t*(aold(2)+anew(2))/2;

%Final, more accurate values for x and y
x(end) = x(end-1) + t*(vxnew + vx)/2;
y(end) = y(end-1) + t*(vynew + vy)/2;

%And updating these as the new velocities
vx = vxnew;
vy = vynew;

end    

%Then we construct a vector for the time steps, for the entire journey.
tout = 0:t:((length(x)-1)*t);

 %And then create a position vector which includes the x and y positions.
pos = zeros(length(x),2);
pos(:,1) = x;
pos(:,2) = y;

end
```

Comment: `simulaterocketmovement` has a loop that runs until it’s close to the moon, but what if that angle doesn’t bring it close to the moon?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Then wouldn't the length of x keep increasing, and so the length of the vector tout increases which is caught by the if loop in the first set of code?

Comment: If the function never exits, then that `if` is never executed. You might want to put that condition inside the inner loop. I recommend that you step through your code using the debugger to understand the flow of control.